# How can I make a "SELECT SUM(column) in splunk?

Tags: splunk

I want to make a select sum(value) to get only something like

```
gender     value
Femenino   18500
Masculino  11000
```

from this Statistics.

[image: Splunk UI]

This is my search

"`source=users| JOIN type=inner id [ SEARCH source=bills | rename id_user AS id ] | top gender`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your query:

```
| stats sum(value) as value by gender
```